# PhoneGap on Symbian: Does native side work?

Tags: qt, cordova, symbian

I created application on PhoneGap for iOS and Android.

But if I import it to Symbian, my native side is not working :(

And I have some questions:

- Native side must be working in WGZ and Qt applications or only in Qt applications?
- Do you have or know working examples using camera and/or geolocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the PhoneGap build website to compile your project. It will give you the executable files of all the plateforms. Try install the wgz file for symbian. Mine is working.

They should be working on both the WGZ and Qt.

I tried both the api(camera/geolocation) from the PhoneGap/Cordova site and both are working fine.

Only thing to notice:
1) Include the phonegap.js file in your www folder for symbian PhoneGap. You can find it from PhoneGap sample projects.

2) Refer this file in the javascript files